# Copying from existing project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have some problem in visual studio.Ok here is the scenario

first i add an existing project to my project in visual studio,and after that i tried to compile and run and it works properly...and then i exit the visual studio. and copy the folder or the visual studio solutions into my laptop.after that i open the visual solutions in my laptop after the visual studio loads,the project that i add before is greyed out and empty...can you help me on this please how can i see back my project that i add before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add an existing project to a solution, you're adding a link.  You didn't copy the actual project, you just copied the link, which shows as empty on your laptop.

Right-click on the project and look at the properties, you should see the location.  This should show you the problem.

You won't be able to recover that project without going back to the source, you don't have the code on your laptop.

-t.

Comment: how can i copy the actual project?

Comment: I think the easiest way is to just copy over the project folder and delete/re-add it to your solution.  You can monkey around with the .proj and .sln files with notepad, but it's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you copy the project off your portable drive to your hardrive? Sometimes copying it off external drives has solved that issue for me.